# How to show an image below a div both horizontally centered on the page?

Tags: css, html

I have this layout:
[image: webpage screenshot]

Code here: http://m6000225.ferozo.com/test/

I need the blue and brown image to lay below the main content div, and both be aligned regardless of the window width, both centered horizontally.
I implemented a css tip I read on this site, which is having a div with absolute position and left: 50% and an img inside with relative position and left: -50%.
It works fine, except for the fact that it pushes the page width to the right, as you can see in the screenshot, the scrollbar can be seen.
3rd party lib solutions like jQuery are welcome, but I'd prefer plain CSS.

PS: I also need something similar below the footer, but I guess using the same solution with a negative bottom value should work, right?

PS2: Extending the blue-brown strip to both borders of the window is no problem as I already used another div with absolute position and background-repeat: repeat-x.

Comment: Looks like a simple case of bg image(s) on the body, positioned in the center.

Comment: @Paulie_D but I also need the strip to extend dynamically to the borders of the page, so I need two backgrounds, one with repeat-x, so the other, without repeat, has to be a div, centered.

Comment: But you were actually right @Paulie_D, I did use a background image centered on a div, and it worked. Thanks!
Copy & paste your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: Nope, one bg image in the `html` element, a second on the `body` and, if necessary another on the `div` or `header`. You can, now, also add multiple backgrounds to some elements.

Comment: No need for me to use a generic comment as an answer. If someone wants to use my suggestion for a better formed answer they are welcome to the rep points.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bar is appearing because of the `left: 50%;` on the class `.header-image`.  You should drop that altogether.  Since that tag has a width set, when you push it over 50% it falls outside the window forcing the scroll bar to appear.

After you drop the left call, you should then set the width of that div to the width of the window, not a specific value in pixels.  Use `Width: 100%`.  So, that tag should look like:

```
.header-image {
  height: 245px;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

After that, you'll need to re-center the image contained within the div.  To do that, instead of using positions (which rely on set boundaries), give the element auto margins.  Use :

```
.header-image img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

That will recenter the image.  Please let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: No, I already tried that solution, but the image remains left-aligned, not centered, check the updated code: http://m6000225.ferozo.com/test  
(I'm trying this on Chrome)

Comment: Interesting.  It worked fine for me in FF.  I would be interested in seeing what failed in Chrome - this is fairly common CSS.  Out of curioisty, could you post up this version and see what differed?

Comment: Oops, already overwrote the files both locally and remotely. But it is common CSS indeed and it was the intuitive solution I tried first, but Chrome didn't like it. I think that maybe as it's an absolutely positioned object, a percentage width may not make sense to Chrome in order to calculate auto margins.

Answer (score 0):

Per Paulie_D's suggestion:

```
.header-image {
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 245px;
background-image: url('header.png');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}
That did it.